# How to replace for loop making processing faster?

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop

ive got alot of files to process. Data looks like:

```
         V2              V3   V4
1 ID_0071817               1    1
2          1 201912312200+00 0.36
3          2 201912312300+00 0.36
4          3 202001010000+00 0.38
5 ID_0089011               1 1.00
6          1 202001010200+00 0.36
```

What i now do is:

```
for(j in 1:nrow(data)) { if (data[j,2] == "1") {ID<-data[j,1]}
  data[j,4] <- ID
}
```

which produces:

```
      V2              V3   V4       V4.1
1 ID_0071817               1    1 ID_0071817
2          1 201912312200+00 0.36 ID_0071817
3          2 201912312300+00 0.36 ID_0071817
4          3 202001010000+00 0.38 ID_0071817
5 ID_0089011               1 1.00 ID_0089011
6          1 202001010200+00 0.36 ID_0089011
```

problem is that this is way too slow way to process the whole data. Single file takes like 5min ive got few thousand of these.

Comment: Please add a language tag - is it `R` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try `cumsum` like below

```
transform(
  df,
  V4.1 = V2[V3 == 1][cumsum(V3 == 1)]
)
```

which gives

```
          V2              V3   V4       V4.1
1 ID_0071817               1 1.00 ID_0071817
2          1 201912312200+00 0.36 ID_0071817
3          2 201912312300+00 0.36 ID_0071817
4          3 202001010000+00 0.38 ID_0071817
5 ID_0089011               1 1.00 ID_0089011
6          1 202001010200+00 0.36 ID_0089011
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V2 = c("ID_0071817", "1", "2", "3", "ID_0089011", 
"1"), V3 = c("1", "201912312200+00", "201912312300+00", "202001010000+00",
"1", "202001010200+00"), V4 = c(1, 0.36, 0.36, 0.38, 1, 0.36)), class = "data.frame", row.names 
= c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```